# how to add the number of items at the end of the linq query

Tags: linq

i have the following LINQ

```
        public IEnumerable<TurbineStatus> turStatus()
    {

        var result = (from s in _db.masterData
                      group s by s.current_turbine_status into g
                      select new TurbineStatus
                      {
                          status = g.Key,
                          numberOfTurbines = g.Count()

                      }
                    ).ToList().OrderByDescending(s => s.status);
        return result;
    }
```

my class:

```
    public class TurbineStatus
{

    public string status { get; set; }
    public int numberOfTurbines { get; set; }
    public int allTurbines { get; set; }

}
```

i gives me the number of turbines according to the status,for example, 5turbines STOP,6 turbines RUN,10 turbines Link Down and so on,i also need to have sum of all these statuses,in my TurbinesStatus class i have a field which is int and named it allTurbines,how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better for performance reasons to let the DB handle sorting and then once the result is materialized, you can extract the sum of the turbines count:

```
var result = 
(
   from s in _db.masterData
   group s by s.current_turbine_status into g
   select new TurbineStatus
   {
      status = g.Key,
      numberOfTurbines = g.Count()                             
   } into statusGroup
   orderby statusGroup.status descending
   select statusGroup
).ToList();

int totalTurbines = groups.Sum(statusGroup => statusGroup.numberOfTurbines);
```

To return both as a TurbinesStatus instance:

```
public class TurbinesStatus
{
    public IReadOnlyList<TurbineStatus> TurbineStatuses { get; }
    public int TotalCount { get; }

    public TurbinesStatus(IReadOnlyList<TurbineStatus> turbineStatuses)
    {
        TurbineStatuses = turbineStatuses;
        TotalCount = turbineStatuses.Sum(ts => ts.numberOfTurbines);
    }
}
```

and then

```
public TurbinesStatus turStatus()
{
    var statuses = 
    (
       from s in _db.masterData
       group s by s.current_turbine_status into g
       select new TurbineStatus
       {
          status = g.Key,
          numberOfTurbines = g.Count()                             
       } into statusGroup
       orderby statusGroup.status descending
    ).ToList();
    
    return new TurbinesStatus(statuses);
}
```

Comment: my return type is  public IEnumerable<TurbineStatus> turStatus() how can i send them all in one go?

Comment: @mortezasol I don't understand, your linq query returns groups, not `TurbineStatus` instances. Can you be more specific on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Still unclear, what do you expect the method to return? In my code, result contains the list of `TurbineStatus` instances sorted by status descending. Do you want to add the total number of turbines to the result of the method?

Comment: number of turbines based on their status,

Comment: So `TurbinesStatus` should have a `IEnumerable<TurbineStatus> Statuses` property (= result of the linq query) as well as the total count of statuses?

Comment: i updated my question by adding the class,can you please explain me why should i add IEnumerable<TurbineStatus> Statuses,i really appreciate if you tell me the reason

Comment: I think this is what you need, a class holding the `masterData` records, grouped by turbine status with #items per group + the total number of turbines. You don't need to duplicate the total number of turbines in each `TurbineStatus` instance

Comment: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'turbinesStatuses' of 'TurbinesStatus.TurbineStatus(IReadOnlyList<TurbinesStatus i get this error on the linq

Comment: OK, I've created a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7RRidu) to make sure we were on the same page: does it meet your needs?